# Mix_PlayMusic() not playing music

Tags: c, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I have this program which used to load mp3 file from cmd argument but when i use the Mix_PlayMusic the audio isn't playing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>

Mix_Music *mp3 = NULL;

bool loadmedia(char *filepath);
void play();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    bool success;   

   if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }


    if(Mix_OpenAudio(44100,MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT,2,2048)<0){
        printf("SDL_mixer could not be initialized %s\n",Mix_GetError());
        success = false;
    }

    char *file = argv[1];

    bool status= loadmedia(file);

   
}


bool loadmedia(char *file_path){
    bool success = true;

    printf("%s is path\n",file_path);

    mp3 = Mix_LoadMUS(file_path);

    if(mp3==NULL){
        printf("media load failed\n");
        success = false;
    }
    else{
                    printf("media loaded succefully\n");
                    Mix_PlayMusic(mp3,-1);

                    play();
        
    }

    return success;

}

void play(){

    Mix_FreeMusic(mp3);
}
```

i use sdl2 and i used both wav and mp3 files but nothing is working.

Comment: `Mix_FreeMusic()` stops any currently playing music.  Why are you calling it *immediately* after `Mix_PlayMusic()`?

Comment: sorry my bad removed it and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem was `SDL_Delay()` wasn't added to program which the file has not time to be played adding `SDL_Delay()` fixed the problem.